# Positioning footer at the bottom of the page

Tags: css, footer

PLEASE help me to make this footer appear at the bottom of the page without "external" CSS

**CSS**

```
 #exefixedfooterdiv {
  background-color: yellow;
  overflow:none; 
  width:100%; 
  height:80px; 
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0%; 
  left:0%;}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="exefixedfooterdiv" >
</div>
```

Comment: you can write the inline CSS.....

Answer (score 0):

you can write the inline CSS like mentioned below code :-

```
<div style="background-color: red;
; overflow:none; width:100%; height:80px; position:fixed; bottom:0%; left:0%;" >
</div>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vNU8s/)

Answer (score 0):

Write in-line styles.

```
<div style="position:absolute;width:100%;height:100px;background:#FF0000;bottom:0;" >
</div>
```

or according to your styles:

```
<div id="exefixedfooterdiv" style="background-color: yellow;
; overflow:none; width:100%; height:80px; position:fixed; bottom:0%; left:0%;"></div>
```

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/PKnbn/)

Answer (score 0):

You can describe the styling inside the div:

```
<div style="background-color: yellow; overflow:none; width:100%; height:80px; position:fixed; bottom:0%; left:0%;" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/PUSrm/2/)**

**CSS**

```
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#exefixedfooterdiv {background-color: yellow;
 overflow:none; width:100%; height:80px; position:fixed; bottom:0;
 }
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="exefixedfooterdiv" >
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to add z-index for position:fixed elements :

```
#exefixedfooterdiv {
   background-color: yellow;
   overflow:none; 
   width:100%; 
   height:80px; 
   position:fixed;
   bottom:0; 
   left:0;
   z-index: 999;
}
```